# MYSQL Restore from file fails

Tags: mysql

after shredding my Ubuntu system, I want to restore databases by the frm/MYD/MYI files I backed up.

I restored my the all custom database folders into /var/lib/mysql 
I left the automatically installed files and db's as they are.

When I open phpmyadmin, I can see all table structures for magento tables, and I have data in wordpress tables. If I click on one of the magento tables, I get 1146 Table 'databsename.core_resource' doesn't exist.

What went wrong there? How can I get tables restored and also the data? The database files I copied have all acceptable sizes, so they do not appear to be empty. Filerights for all database files are on mysql:mysql.

Please help.